# Prevent anonymous bind in LDAP

Tags: spring-security, ldap, spring-security-ldap

Am developing the spring application with LDAP. Is there is any option to prevent the anonymous bind in LDAP. Am using Apache Directory Studio. Even I am giving the simple bind. Anonymous bind is permitted

[image]

Pl. help me to fix this.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Unanswerable without knowing which LDAP server you're using, apart from merely saying 'yes': and off-topic.

Comment: @user207421 I missed to mention. I am using Apache Directory Studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most current LDAP server implementations have an option to disable anonymous binds.

From a LDAP client perspective you can check if the bindDN and password is empty and disallow any such request.

THere is also a "Un-authenticated Bind" term used by some were the bindDN is known but the password is empty which you could also disallow.

-jim